# Can mirrored (shadowed) rdp sessions go fullscreen?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, streaming, mirroring

If I use the `/shadow:1` parameter to mirror a user's screens, the opened rdp window ignores the `/f` and cannot be sent to fullscreen by any means I know of.

In "normal" RDP sessions the user can right-click the top-bar and go to fullscreen, but that control is missing in rdp windows spawned with the `/shadow` parameter.

Why do shadowed rdp sessios behave differently? Is there a way to make it go fullscreen? Preferably with invidual monitors? I want to use rdp shadowing to easily stream individual students' monitors to a beamer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. The only parameters taken into account when shadowing are:

```
Mstsc.exe [/shadow:sessionID [/v:Servername] [/control] [/noConsentPrompt]]
```

Specifically, you cannot specify any parameter for width, height or full-screen.

This limitation has existed
[since 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc772355%28v=ws.11%29),
where it is stated:

> Your session must be capable of supporting the video resolution used at the session that you are remotely controlling or the operation fails.

Comment: A pity there is no way around that, using shadowing to stream things during trainings would have been awesome. Do you know whether MSTSCLib supports shadowing?

Comment: Never used it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround;
you can use Auto Hot Key to force this.

```
^!f::
WinGetTitle, currentWindow, A
IfWinExist %currentWindow%
{
WinMaximize, A 
WinSet, Style, -0xC40000, A
}   
return
```